# Get the number of rows which contain a certain value in one of the columns and display the number in a label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview and sqldatasource.

I want to display in a label, the number of rows from the gridview which contains a certain value in one of the columns (in the `form_load` event)

I thought about looping through all columns of the gridview but it will take a lot of time for this and maybe there's another way of doing this.

Can someone help me finding the "other way"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution would be to let the database handle filtering - you'll get much better performance that way than looping over the data on application server.

Perhaps create another `SqlDataSource` with an SQL statement containing appropriate `WHERE` condition and bind it to your label?